# configuring mysql instance innosetup

Tags: mysql, inno-setup

I am trying to configure mysql instance using the code

```
Filename: "{app}\mysql\bin\mysqld.exe"; Parameters: "--install"; 
WorkingDir: "{app}\mysql\bin";  StatusMsg: "Installing the MySQL Service";
Description: "Installing MySQL Service"; Flags: runhidden; Check: MySQL_Is;


Filename: {app}\mysql\bin\MySQLInstanceConfig.exe; 
Parameters:"-i -q ""-l{app}\mysql\mysql_install_log.txt"" ""-nMySQL Server 5.5"" ""-p{app}\mysql"" -v5.5.23 ""-t{app}\mysql\my-template.ini"" ""-c{app}\mysql\mysql.ini"" ServerType=SERVER DatabaseType=MIXED Port=3306 StrictMode=yes ConnectionCount=15 Charset=utf8 ServiceName=MYSQL AddBinToPath=yes RootPassword=mypass"; 
WorkingDir: {app}; StatusMsg: Configuring MySQL services; 
Description: Configuring MySQL Service; Flags: runhidden 



[Code]
function MySQL_Is(): Boolean;
var
iResultCode: Integer;
AppPath: String;
begin
  Result := true;
  if (not RegKeyExists(HKLM, 'SOFTWARE\MySQL AB\MySQL Server 5.5')) or 
   (not FileExists(ExpandConstant('{reg:HKLM\SOFTWARE\MySQL AB\MySQL Server 5.5,Location}\bin\mysql.exe'))) 
  then begin
     ExtractTemporaryFile('mysql-5.5.11-win32.msi');
     AppPath := ExpandConstant('{app}')
     Exec('msiexec.exe', '/i mysql-5.5.11-win32.msi /qn INSTALLDIR="' + AppPath + '\mysql"  DATADIR="' + AppPath + 'mysql\data"', 
      ExpandConstant('{tmp}'), SW_HIDE, ewWaitUntilTerminated, iResultCode);
         if not FileExists(ExpandConstant('{reg:HKLM\SOFTWARE\MySQL AB\MySQL Server 5.5,Location}\bin\mysql.exe')) then begin
            MsgBox('Something went wrong! Installation should be terminated' + AppPath, 
              mbInformation, MB_OK);
            Result := false;
         end;
  end;
end;
```

I get the following error in the debugger

> [15:35:46.583]   Type: Exec [15:35:46.588]   Filename: C:\Program
>   Files (x86)\MyCompany Inc\MyApp\mysql\bin\MySQLInstanceConfig.exe
>   [15:35:46.592]   Parameters: -i -q "-lC:\Program Files (x86)\MyCompany
>   Inc\MyApp\mysql\mysql_install_log.txt" "-nMySQL Server 5.5"
>   "-pC:\Program Files (x86)\MyCompany Inc\MyApp\mysql" -v5.5.23
>   "-tC:\Program Files (x86)\MyCompany Inc\MyApp\mysql\my-template.ini"
>   "-cC:\Program Files (x86)\MyCompany Inc\MyApp\mysql\mysql.ini"
>   ServerType=SERVER DatabaseType=MIXED Port=3306 StrictMode=yes
>   ConnectionCount=15 Charset=utf8 ServiceName=MYSQL AddBinToPath=yes
>   RootPassword=mypass [15:36:12.122]   Process exit code: 3

This is the log file created during execution of the configuration

> ---------------------------------------- Welcome to the MySQL Server Instance Configuration Wizard 1.0.17.0 Date: 2016-09-02 15:35:49
>
> Installing service ...
>
> Product Name:         MySQL Server 5.5 Version:              5.5.23
>   Installation Path:    C:\Program Files (x86)\MyCompany
>   Inc\MyApp\mysql\
>
> Creating configuration file C:\Program Files (x86)\MyCompany
>   Inc\MyApp\mysql\mysql.ini using template C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\MyCompany Inc\MyApp\mysql\my-template.ini. Options: SERVER MIXED
>   STRICTMODE
>
> Variables: active_connections: 15 port: 3306 default-character-set:
>   utf8 basedir: "C:/Program Files (x86)/MyCompany Inc/MyApp/mysql/"
>   datadir: "C:/Program Files (x86)/MyCompany Inc/MyApp/mysql/Data/"
>
> Creating Windows service entry. Service name: "MYSQL" Parameters:
>   "C:\Program Files (x86)\MyCompany Inc\MyApp\mysql\bin\mysqld"
>   --defaults-file="C:\Program Files (x86)\MyCompany Inc\MyApp\mysql\mysql.ini" MYSQL. Cannot create Windows service for
>   MYSQL. Error: 0

What could be the cause?

Comment: Again, did you try the same command on command-line? What do you get?

Comment: did you mean if I tried it manually before running inno setup, see the log file generated?

Comment: Sorry, I do not understand. The log you have added, is from Inno Setup or from a standalone run?

Comment: It is from inno run, if you look at the inno script, you will see `mysql_install_log.txt`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to find the solution to the problem,

first i checked the event viewer, and found that MySql services was giving and error `unknown/unsupported storage engine innodb` so i googled online to find the solution

It turns out that the two log files `ib_logfile0, ib_logfile1` found in `mysql\data` directory were the culprit

I deleted them after uninstalling MySql and ran my application setup again which ran successfully